# How to handle many API calls with Swift 3 GCD

Tags: swift, api, csv, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I am building an swift app to interact with an MDM API to do large numbers of updates via PUT commands, and I am running in to issues with how to handle the massive numbers of API calls without overloading the servers.

I am parsing through a CSV, and each line is an update. If I run the commands asynchronously, it generates and sends ALL of the API calls immediately, which the server doesn't like.

But if I run the commands synchronously, it freezes my GUI which is less than ideal, as the end user doesn't know what's going on, how long is left, if things are failing, etc.

I have also tried creating my own NSOperation queue and setting the max number of items to like 5, and then putting the synchronous function in there, but that doesn't seem to work very well either. It still freezes the GUI with some really random UI updates that seem buggy at best.

The servers can handle 5-10 requests at a time, but these CSV files can be upwards of 5,000 lines sometimes.

So how can I limit the number of simultaneous PUT requests going out in my loop, while not having the GUI freeze on me? To be honest, I don't even really care if the end user can interact with the GUI while it's running, I just want to be able to provide feedback on the lines that have run so far.

---

I have a wrapper which a colleague wrote most of, and the async function looks like this:

```
func sendRequest(endpoint: String, method: HTTPMethod, base64credentials: String, dataType: DataType, body: Data?, queue: DispatchQueue, handler: @escaping (Response)->Swift.Void) {
    let url = self.resourceURL.appendingPathComponent(endpoint)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
    request.httpMethod = "\(method)"

    var headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64credentials)"]
    switch dataType {
    case .json:
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
        if let obj = body {
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            } catch {
                queue.async {
                    handler(.badRequest)
                }
                return
            }
        }
    case .xml:
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml"
        headers["Accept"] = "application/xml"
        request.httpBody = body
        /*if let obj = body {
            request.httpBody = (obj as! XMLDocument).xmlData
        }*/
    }
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    session.dataTask(with: request) {
        var response: Response
        if let error = $2 {
            response = .error(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = $1 as! HTTPURLResponse
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
            case 200..<299:
                if let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
                    response = .json(object)
                } else if let object = try? XMLDocument(data: $0!, options: 0) {
                    response = .xml(object)
                } else {
                    response = .success
                }
            default:
                response = .httpCode(httpResponse.statusCode)
            }
        }

        queue.async {
            handler(response)
        }
        }.resume()
```

Then, there is a synchronous option which uses semaphore, which looks like this:

```
    func sendRequestAndWait(endpoint: String, method: HTTPMethod, base64credentials: String, dataType: DataType, body: Data?) -> Response {
    var response: Response!
    let semephore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    sendRequest(endpoint: endpoint, method: method, base64credentials: base64credentials, dataType: dataType, body: body, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)) {
        response = $0
        semephore.signal()
    }
    semephore.wait()
    return response
}
```

Usage information is as follows:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

let client = JSSClient(urlString: "https://my.mdm.server:8443/", allowUntrusted: true)
let credentials = JSSClient.Credentials(username: "admin", password: "ObviouslyNotReal")


func asynchronousRequestExample() {
    print("Sending asynchronous request")

    client.sendRequest(endpoint: "computers", method: .get, credentials: credentials, dataType: .xml, body: nil, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (response) in

        print("Response recieved")

        switch response {
        case .badRequest:
            print("Bad request")
        case .error(let error):
            print("Receieved error:\n\(error)")
        case .httpCode(let code):
            print("Request failed with http status code \(code)")
        case .json(let json):
            print("Received JSON response:\n\(json)")
        case .success:
            print("Success with empty response")
        case .xml(let xml):
            print("Received XML response:\n\(xml.xmlString(withOptions: Int(XMLNode.Options.nodePrettyPrint.rawValue)))")
        }

        print("Completed")
    }

    print("Request sent")

}

func synchronousRequestExample() {
    print("Sending synchronous request")

    let response = client.sendRequestAndWait(endpoint:  "computers", method: .get,credentials: credentials, dataType: .json, body: nil)

    print("Response recieved")

    switch response {
    case .badRequest:
        print("Bad request")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Receieved error:\n\(error)")
    case .httpCode(let code):
        print("Request failed with http status code \(code)")
    case .json(let json):
        print("Received JSON response:\n\(json)")
    case .success:
        print("Success with empty response")
    case .xml(let xml):
        print("Received XML response:\n\(xml.xmlString(withOptions: Int(XMLNode.Options.nodePrettyPrint.rawValue)))")
    }

    print("Completed")
}


override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    synchronousRequestExample()
    asynchronousRequestExample()

}
```

I have modified the send functions slightly, so that they take base64 encoded credentials off the bat, and maybe one or two other things.

Comment: NSOperation queue is a suitable solution, but you need to ensure it is asynchronous so it doesn't block.

Comment: You mean putting synchronous API calls into an async NSOperation queue with a limit on max simultaneous commands? 

I had a feeling this may be the direction I needed to go, but it doesn't seem to behave very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I got this covered! I decided to climb out of the rabbit hole a ways and simplify things. I wrote my own session instead of relying on the wrapper, and set up semaphores in it, threw it in an `OperationQueue` and it seems to be working perfectly.

This was the video I followed to set up my simplified semaphores request. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4k8sN8WdaM

I'll have to tweak the below code to be a PUT instead of the GET I've been using for testing, but that part is easy.

```
//print (row[0])
    let myOpQueue = OperationQueue()
    myOpQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    var i = 0
    while i < 10 {
        let myURL = NSURL(string: "https://my.server.com/APIResources/computers/id/\(i)")
        myOpQueue.addOperation {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Basic 123456789ABCDEFG=", "Content-Type" : "text/xml", "Accept" : "text/xml"]
            let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print(httpResponse.statusCode)
                    semaphore.signal()
                    self.lblLine.stringValue = "\(i)"
                    self.appendLogString(stringToAppend: "\(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    print(myURL!)

                }
                if error == nil {
                    print("No Errors")
                    print("")
                } else {
                    print(error!)
                }
            })

            task.resume()
            semaphore.wait()

        }
        i += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just chain operations to send 3/4 requests at a time per operation?

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

Just so you know, NSOperation (also abstracted by Operation with Swift3) are running by default on background threads. Just be careful to not run heavy tasks in your completion block that might run tasks on the main thread (this will freeze your UI).

The only other case I see that can freeze your UI is by executing too many operations at once.

Comment: The biggest issue I'm personally running in to is that it seems to believe its job is done as soon as the request is CREATED, not once it has completed. So when I try to tell it to just send 3/4 requests at a time, it goes "oh, well, job done then" and then sends 3/4 more, repeat until all 100-1000 are created and hammering the server. The semaphore `sendResponseAndWait` function seems to resolve this.. so should I be packing the kick off of that into an operation that I can queue?

Comment: If I could see the code, maybe I could identify the problem but OperationQueue are made to execute one after the other so it should work as expected. I'm using it in my project too. One thing to remember is an Operation starts as soon as added to the queue is it's the only one in the queue otherwise, it's put at the end of the queue and waits for the operation to be finished. It's possible that you call a dispatch_async on another queue  within your operation and if you put the heavy tasks within the block, the queue will get consumed instantly and you will have the result you just described.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. i added usage information to the OP. The functions do have a dispatch queue call in them. But I would think that wouldn't ben an issue, because it's just dispatching returning the response. Apologies for my ignorance here, this is my first swift project, and my first programming outside of bash/python. This is my last big hurdle, and then the app is done.